# ¿Como obtengo los ID y el VALUE de un arreglo de input text?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una pantalla que agrega imágenes a la base de datos y después de hacerlo, las listo agregando una caja de texto en la que voy a capturar su DESCRIPCIÓN, ejemplo:

```
<form>
    <input id="1" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
    <input id="2" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
    <input id="3" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
</form>

<a type="button" onclick="javascript: agregarPasoDieciseis()">Finalizar</a>
```

Javascript

```
function agregarPasoDieciseis() {

    var descripcion = document.getElementsByName("ftp_desc").value;        
    alert(descripcion);
}
```

Como obtengo los ID y el VALUE de los input con Javascript, el código anterior no me funciono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByName` te regresa un conjunto de objetos con el nombre `ftp_des`, tienes que acceder a ellos a través de un ciclo como si fuera un arreglo y obtener así sus atributos id y value.

```js
var docs = document.getElementsByName('ftp_desc');

for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
 console.log('id: ' + docs[i].id + ',' + 'value: ' + docs[i].value);
}
```

```html
<input id="1" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
<input id="2" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
<input id="3" name="ftp_desc"  maxlength="256" placeholder="Añade una descripción" required="required" type="text">
```

Comment: Tengo una duda más, ya obtengo los ID y los VALUE, quiero crear con esos datos un STRING pero no me funciono con esto: 
for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {      
        id_img+= docs[i].id + ",";
        val_img+= docs[i].velue +",";
    }
alert("IDs" + id_img + " -  VALORES "+ val_img);

Comment: Eso ya sería en otra pregunta por favor